# audio watermark with sox won't work in php

Tags: php, audio, vps, watermark, sox

When I am using command line on hosting panel,

```
sox -m '|sox /home/stockchu/public_html/content/watermark_audio.mp3 -p pad 4 repeat 5' /home/stockchu/public_html/content/sound.mp3 /home/stockchu/public_html/content/sound_watermarked3.mp3
```

it is working! But when I am do same on PHP,

```
$com="sox -m '|sox ".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/content/watermark_audio.mp3 -p pad 4 repeat 5' ".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/content/sound.mp3 ".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/content/sound_watermarked3.mp3";
echo($com."<br>");
exec($com);
```

nothing is happening!

What's wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- Use full path to the executable, instead of just `sox`. You can find the full path by typing `which sox` in terminal
- Make sure you are not running PHP in [safe_mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php)
- Make sure PHP interpreter has permissions to run sox.